# How can I change slice color of a Tdbchart runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pie-chart

I use a TDBChart in a Delphi7 project which gets its data from a TADOQuery.Chart. The type of TDBChart is Pie and the slices color is default colors (yellow, red, green).

I want to change the color of slices runtime. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used TChart instead of TDbChart and wrote these codes for gettig value from TAdoQuery:

```
with AdoQuery1 do
  begin
    i := 1;
    while not Eof do
      begin          
        chart1.Series[0].Add(fieldbyname('count').AsInteger,fieldbyname('statename').AsString,colors[i]);
        i := (i+1) mod 10;
        Next;
      end;
   end;
```

when: colors is an array of colors we want.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of a specific slide by:

```
  chart1.Series[1].ValueColor[0] := clRed;
  chart1.Series[1].ValueColor[1] := clYellow;
  chart1.Series[1].ValueColor[2] := clGreen;
```